# Ajax redirecting successfully with button tag but not with tag input type=button?

Tags: html, jquery

I am new to this website, I have found it is resource to clarify my questions. I have written below ajax code in Jquery. It invokes the ajax code with onclick action and then it redirects into page Display_Mobiles.php.

Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var imgs = {
               input_action : function(config){
                   this.config=config;

                        $.ajax({
                            type:'GET',
                            url:'Display_Mobiles.php',
                            data: this.config.form2.serialize(),

                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data.responseText);


                            }
                        });//end of ajax request

             }
          }             

         $('.Mobile_Category li button').on('click',function(e){               

                       imgs.input_action({form2:$('home_left #Mobile_Category')});   

            });
         });
```

HTML part:

```
     <div class="home_left">
                <form action="Display_Mobiles.php" id="Mobile_Category" method="GET">

                       <div class="Mobile_Category"> 
                          <H2>Category</H2>                             
                          <li><button name="category" value="samsung">samsung </button></li>
                     </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The above code worked perfectly and redirected correctly with correct parameters with button as form element but when i change button tag to input tag with type= button, it is not redirecting. It is invoking the event and calling the function input_action but not redirecting to the page Display_Mobiles.php page. The changes to the code is specified below.

I made below changes to the above code

1. I have changed the button tag (bolded above ) to
2. event to ( just changed the event to call input tag instead of button.

   ```
   $('.Mobile_Category li input').on('click',function(e){           

      imgs.input_action({form2:$('home_left #Mobile_Category')});  
   });
   ```

Please correct me , if i have done anything wrong... thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably not the cause of this particular problem, but your `LI` needs to live inside of a `UL` or `OL`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you change your element to another element, update your selector. Change this code

```
$('.Mobile_Category li button')
```

to

```
$('.Mobile_Category input[type="button"]')
```